# dashboard widget form not submit mails

Tags: php, plugin-development, widgets

I'm adding for the first time a wordpress dashboard widget. I'm creating a simple form to give the user the ability to send support request directly from wp dashboard. I'm not sure if all the code is working, during a test, I've noticed that the form will not submit the mail message. Can anyone help me?

```
function uptheme_support_dashboard_widgets()
  {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_help_widget', 'Premium Ticket System', 'custom_dashboard_help');
  }

  function custom_dashboard_help()
  {
    $current_theme = wp_get_theme( 'uptheme-panel' );
    ?>
      <p><?php _e('Hi! you are using the custom theme '. esc_html($current_theme) ); ?></p>
      <p><?php _e('Use the form to request support for your theme.'); ?></p>
      <form method="POST">
      <p><?php _e('Email'); ?></p>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" />
      <p><?php _e('Request type'); ?></p>
        <select name="support_ticket_type">
          <option value=""><?php _e('Support request'); ?></option>
          <option value=""><?php _e('Modification request'); ?></option>
        </select>
      <p><?php _e('Message'); ?></p>
        <textarea class="widefat" name="support_message"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit_support_ticket">
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'submit_support_ticket', 'support_ticket_hash' ); ?>
        <button class="btn-primary" type="submit" class=""><?php _e('Invia'); ?></button>
      </form>
      <small><?php _e('Theme powered by'); ?><a href="#"><?php _e('theme author'); ?></a></small>
    <?php
  }
  add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'uptheme_support_dashboard_widgets');


  function _submit_support_ticket()
  {
    if( isset($_POST['support_ticket_hash']) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['support_ticket_hash'], 'submit_support_ticket' ) ){
      //echo '';
      exit;
    }
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['support_ticket_type'];
    $message = $_POST['support_message'];
    $to = 'mymail@provider.com';
    $headers[] = "From: <$email>";
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
  }
  add_action( 'admin_post_submit_support_ticket', '_submit_support_ticket' );
```

Comment: Did you forget the form's `action`? It should submit to `admin-post.php`..

Comment: I didn't set it, I need to try. Is the same also for ajax `wp_ajax_` ?

Comment: Also, that `isset($_POST['support_ticket_hash'])` should be `! isset($_POST['support_ticket_hash'])`. Otherwise, the page would exit even if there was actually a valid nonce.

Comment: And about that `wp_ajax_`, I'm not sure what you mean, but if you use that hook, then your AJAX request should be sent to `admin-ajax.php`. The `admin_post_` hooks are for regular/non-AJAX form submissions, but their syntax is identical to the `wp_ajax_` hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues I see in your code:

1. Your form doesn't have an `action` set. You should add it and set the value to `admin-post.php`.

   ```php
   <form method="POST" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ); ?>">
   ```

   Because the function which processes the form and then sends the email is hooked to `admin_post_submit_support_ticket` (i.e. [`admin_post_<action>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_action/)) and that hook is fired only on `wp-admin/admin-post.php`.
2. In `_submit_support_ticket()`, the `isset($_POST['support_ticket_hash'])` should be `! isset($_POST['support_ticket_hash'])` because if not, the page would exit even if there was actually a valid nonce.

   ```php
   if( ! isset($_POST['support_ticket_hash']) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['support_ticket_hash'], 'submit_support_ticket' ) ){
     //echo '';
     exit;
   }
   ```
3. The email *subject* is actually empty and that will not send the email. So make sure that your "Request type" drop-down has valid options (currently, the `option`'s `value` is empty).

   ```php
   wp_mail( 'test@example.com', '', 'Testing' );   // bad; subject is empty
   wp_mail( 'test@example.com', 'Hi', 'Testing' ); // good; subject is good..
   ```

   In fact, if you look at [`wp_mail()`'s docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/), the subject is a required parameter. So once again, make sure the `<option>` has a good subject, although it might be preferred to compose the subject in your PHP and not sent as-is as coming from the form.

   ```html
   <p><?php _e('Request type'); ?></p>
   <select name="support_ticket_type">
     <option value="Support request"><?php _e('Support request'); ?></option>
     <option value="Modification request"><?php _e('Modification request'); ?></option>
   </select>
   ```

And after the email is sent, you should send the user back to the dashboard page to prevent them from seeing a blank page. So after the `wp_mail()` call, you could do:

```php
wp_redirect( admin_url() );
exit;
```

Also, you should *always* [sanitize](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-input/) user-supplied data. Never trust their input even if you actually trust the person...

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've added the action to the form `action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php'));?>"` and it seems working now. I need a way to redirect back to the dashboard the user after the form subission. do you have a suggestion? I think I will test also with ajax, in this way I can avoid to refresh the page after ticket submission .

Comment: Yes, I was updating the answer when your comment came in. And yes, I'd also use AJAX, but that's another story. :)